# Throw "FileIOException:Not a directory" on create directory in blackberry application

Tags: blackberry, file-io, create-directory

I want to create my Application directory to save my configuration file. but blackberry simulator throws an exception on creating directory. i have tried the following code.

```
try {
FileConnection myAppDir = (FileConnection) Connector.open("file:///store/home/user/myAppDir", Connector.READ_WRITE);
    if (!myAppDir.exists()){
        myAppDir.mkdir(); // Exception throw here
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Exception throw

```
net.rim.device.api.io.file.FileIOException: Not a directory
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried adding a forward-slash to the end of your path so the connector knows it's a directory?

```
try {
FileConnection myAppDir = (FileConnection) Connector.open("file:///store/home/user/myAppDir/", Connector.READ_WRITE);
    if (!myAppDir.exists()){
        myAppDir.mkdir(); // Exception throw here
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure the device/simulator you're testing on has internal storage? You should use [FileSystemRegistry](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.0.0api/javax/microedition/io/file/FileSystemRegistry.html) to get available file system roots, eg from the API docs:

```
   Enumeration rootEnum = FileSystemRegistry.listRoots();
   while (rootEnum.hasMoreElements()) {
      String root = (String) rootEnum.nextElement();
      FileConnection fc = (FileConnection) Connector.open("file:///" + root);
      System.out.println(fc.availableSize());
   }
```